# Search XML nodes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I parsed XML using Nokogiri, and I am trying to get the attribute of a node and its value, but I am not able to get it. The parsed XML, using `(Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml_record))`, looks like:

```
#(Element:0x3fe544ad4544 {
  name = "Article",
  attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe54446c3c8 { name = "Id", value = "1980274" })],
  children = [
    #(Element:0x3fe54446b9b4 { name = "ArticleName", children = [ #(Text "100 Porsches and Me")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe544bf9744 { name = "Locked", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe544bf96b8 { name = "Value", value = "0" })] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe544bf8dbc { name = "OriginalTitle", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe544bf8c54 { name = "N", value = "1" })] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe544bf7dcc { name = "ProductionYear", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe544bf7cb4 { name = "Value", value = "2006" })], children = [ #(Text "2006")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe544b84098 { name = "SalesStart", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe544b83fd0 { name = "Value", value = "1391212800" })], children = [ #(Text "01.02.2014")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe544b834e0 { name = "SalesEnd", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe544b83454 { name = "Value", value = "1548892800" })], children = [ #(Text "31.01.2019")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe545c52758 { name = "Price", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe545c526b8 { name = "Value", value = "3.9900" })], children = [ #(Text "3,99")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe545c51c40 { name = "Runtime", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe545c51b8c { name = "Value", value = "90" })], children = [ #(Text "90")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe545c51038 { name = "FeatureType", attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe545c50f98 { name = "Name", value = "FeatureFilm" })], children = [ #(Text "Film")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe54616158c { name = "OrderNumber", children = [ #(Text "LIG00000075")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe546160d80 { name = "ArticleCode", children = [ #(Text "LHE28409261")] }),
```

When I do `xml_rec.xpath('Article').attr(Id)`it returns nil. 
I don't want to do with "//Article".

Because I am passing each `xml_rec` to a method and when I do "//Article" I get only the first element's ID.

Is there a way to get the the attribute value of root element in Nokogiri?

Comment: xml_rec.at_xpath('//Article').attr('Id') ?

Comment: I am getting the first ID of the xml document when using //Article. I am not sure why it is so even though I am passing in the loop different xml record.

Comment: So is there any way to get it without //Article??

Comment: Use.. `#at_css` for your need..

Comment: Don't ask us to use `inspect` output to diagnose the problem. Instead, do as expected, and supply the raw XML, along with the code you're using to parse it, and the code you're using to select the desired node. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"